# Is Jared Fogle's “Subway Diet” healthy?

Tags: nutrition

Someone told me recently about the [Jared Fogle story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jared_Fogle) and his self-created “Subway Diet.” I didn't know about it since there were no Subway shops in my country at that time.

Is/was this “Subway Diet” healthy?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your question is kind of vague - what is “healthy?”

The “Subway Diet” is unquestionably ***healthier* than** Jared Fogle’s previous “high-fat junk food” diet, **especially coupled with increased physical exercise**.

However, it is not considered to be dietitionally/nutritionally perfect by any stretch of imagination.

Not only there is *no* research supporting the diet as perfect, here’s a direct quote **from Subway's corporate dietitian** accompanying the news release about the promotion:

> “Both Jared Fogle and a Subway Corporate dietitian acknowledged that some elements were missing from the weight-loss plan designed by the Indiana college student. **“It’s great that it worked for him, but I would rather he had eaten a balanced breakfast and more fruits and vegetables,” dietitian Lanette Roulier said in a December 2000 news release.**”
>
> “She pointed out that people’s dietary needs varied, and advised the public to consult with a physician and/or dietitian before starting a weight-loss program.”
>
> “A restrictive diet of only two sandwiches a day is not nutritionally sound. Jared Fogle eliminated fruit and dairy products from his diet. He missed out on the fiber in fruit and nutrients like vitamins A and C. The diet also lacked the calcium found in dairy products.”
>
> “However, the sandwiches provided fiber and vitamins. Poultry like turkey was among the lean proteins recommended in the USDA guidelines. **The federal guide also advised people to limit fat and to participate in regular physical activity. Fogle did both.**”

More details/discussion can be found at:

- [*Ask Yahoo!*: “How effective is the ‘Subway Diet?’”](https://web.archive.org/web/20111122095653/http://ask.yahoo.com/20011012.html)
- [Answers.com](http://www.answers.com/topic/what-research-is-there-on-the-subway-diet-and-is-it-generally-accepted) (dead link/unreferenced)